# curl: How to send HEAD request with request body

Tags: http, curl

I'd like to send a HEAD request with a request body.

So I tried the below commands. But I got some errors.

```
$ curl -X HEAD http://localhost:8080 -d "test"
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.
curl: (18) transfer closed with 11 bytes remaining to read
```

or I tried this one:

```
$ curl -I http://localhost:8080 -d "test"
Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST
Warning: (-d, --data) and HEAD (-I, --head).
```

I think that RFC doesn't prohibit sending HEAD request with a request body.

How can I send ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, with `-d`/`--data`, method "`POST`" is used.

With `-I`/`--head` you sugest to use "`HEAD`" method.

How your service accept which method (POST or HEAD) ?

I use "`https://httpbin.org`" site for testing.

With cURL, yout could use, POST like this:

```sh
$ curl --silent --include https://httpbin.org/post -d "data=spam_and_eggs"
HTTP/2 200 
date: Thu, 30 Sep 2021 18:57:02 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 438
server: gunicorn/19.9.0
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true

{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "data": "spam_and_eggs"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "18", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.71.1", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6156087e-6b04f4645dce993909a95b24"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "86.245.210.158", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

or "`HEAD`" method:

```sh
$ curl --silent -X HEAD --include https://httpbin.org/headers -d "data=spam_and_eggs"
HTTP/2 200 
date: Thu, 30 Sep 2021 18:58:30 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 260
server: gunicorn/19.9.0
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

I inspected with `strace` (with the HTTP protocol) the `HEAD` request with data are passed to the server:

```
sendto(5, "HEAD /headers HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.71.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Length: 18\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\ndata=spam_and_eggs", 170, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 170
```

Of course, without "`--silent`" option, the warning message appears:

```
Warning: Setting custom HTTP method to HEAD with -X/--request may not work the 
Warning: way you want. Consider using -I/--head instead.
```

My research are based on this very old post: https://serverfault.com/questions/140149/difference-between-curl-i-and-curl-x-head

Comment: Thank you for your answering. In my environment, the server can get POST and HEAD requests. And I'd like to send HEAD request with a request body. curl --silent -X HEAD --include http://localhost:8080 -d "test" got an error that "curl: (18) transfer closed with 11 bytes remaining to read". And I couldn't send a request body to the server. In curl, HEAD request mustn't send ?

Comment: Which cURL version do you use ? I use 7.71.1  . Error 18, may be came from server : 1. An incorrect Content-Length header was sent by the peer. 2. The connection gets timed-out as keep-alives were not sent to keep the connection going on. @see: https://bobcares.com/blog/curl-18-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining/